# What is the best way to use Razor in a console application

Tags: c#, razor, console-application

I know similar questions have been asked before, but the only answers are six years old, and the projects people refer to seem like they're not being maintained.

I want to use Razor in a console app or a class library to render HTML. I would also like to have working Intellisense in the .cshtml files.

Currently, I am able to jury-rig this by doing the following:

- Create console app.
- Add .cshtml file.
- In Properties, set the `Custom Tool` property to `RazorTemplatePreprocessor`

This causes Razor syntax to be recognized. So if you have `Test.cshtml`, it generates a class called `Test` that you can use like so:

```
var test = new Test();
test.Model = "Hi there";
var html = test.GenerateString();

Console.WriteLine(html);
```

This is just about good enough for my purposes. However, the actual coding experience within the .cshtml file is pretty broken:

- There are red squigglies all over the place complaining about:
- Not being able to use `var` because it's C# 2.
- Saying the type or namespace of various types can't be found.
- The above is especially true of types imported from other libraries.
- The `@model` keyword is not recognized.
- Intellisense sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Weirdly, if you just ignore all of these errors, the HTML is actually generated correctly, including use of the libraries and @model keyword that the Razor engine complained about. However, this causes major mental clutter because if you have any number of .cshtml files, you very quickly get into hundreds and thousands of these errors mixed in with real errors.

Is there anything I can do to cause the actual Razor coding experience to work more like it does in an ASP.NET web app?

Comment: Check out my 6 months old answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47756437/403671 it's pure razor w/o any ASP.NET nor MVC dependency. Note that .cshtml files are not "razor", they are ASP.NET MVC so you won't have that in a razor console app (unless you emulate it in some way).

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the reply. This is really great! One drawback is that it seems that the idea is to work with files as just text with no editor support. Is there any way to get some basic design-time support within Visual Studio just so that it will recognize Razor blocks and HTML, for example?

Comment: That I don't know, and have not investigated.

Comment: You can simply use [run-time t4 templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713817/3110834). You can download/clone a working example [here](https://github.com/r-aghaei/HtmlUsingRuntimeT4).

Answer (score 7):

**I have been working on this sporadically since I asked the question nearly two years ago, and I believe I have a 99% non-clunky solution.** Everything below works for me in **Visual Studio 16.4.5**.

Here's what I have learned about getting Razor to work in console and library projects.

1. Everything seems to work with the least trouble if create and consume your Razor files in a .NET Core console app.
2. You can also put your Razor files in a .NET Standard library and consume them from a .NET Core console app, though in this case there is some minor ugliness in Solution Explorer. I don't think it has any effect on functionality, however.
3. Either way, both the `@model` and the `@using` keywords work correctly, Intellisense works correctly, lambda expressions work correctly, everything seems to work properly.

Here's what you have to do:

**To add a Razor file:**

Add a new HTML file, but name the file with a `.cshtml` extension.

Select the file in Solution Explorer. In the Properties window, under Custom Tool, enter `RazorTemplatePreprocessor`. A `.cs` file will immediately be generated.

**To consume the generated class:**

```
var razor = new MyRazorClass();
razor.Model = "Hello from Razor";       // Assumes @model string in the Razor file; custom classes are fine too.
var html = razor.GenerateString();
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

**To resolve the errors in the Error List** (which incidentally do not seem to affect functionality but certainly create mental clutter):

Add NuGet references to:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
```

If you are adding your Razor files to a .NET Standard library, you'll get a bunch of the following errors:

```
Feature 'nullable reference types' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.
```

To fix this, add the following two lines to the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>                         <!-- Add this line -->
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>                      <!-- Add this line -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

At this point, the project should compile with no errors or warnings!

However, it doesn't work perfectly. There some oddities, which give me some concern that things might unexpectedly break on me in the future.

**These problems only seem to occur when using Razor files from .NET Standard libraries:**

1. The Solution Explorer sometimes shows the descendants of the `.cshtml` file in two different ways:

a. In what I believe is the correct way, the `.cshtml` file has as its only descendant a generated `.cs` file. That file in turn has two generated classes, `YourRazorClass` and `YourRazorClassBase`. Each of those can be expanded to show the class members, which have nice, human-readable names.

b. Sometimes, however, an underscore-prefixed class appears as a direct descendant of the `.cshtml` file (e.g., `_MyTestRazorClass`), Also, its class members are different.

This seems to appear and disappear from the Solution Explorer and I don't think it causes any harm, but it certainly causes some mental clutter as you wonder what on earth is going on.

2. In Solution Explorer, under the `[Project Name]` > `Dependencies` > `Analyzers`, there are a bunch of warnings that get propagated up into the same section of any project that consumes the library. This also creates mental clutter. Fortunately, you can turn these off by doing the following:

a. Right-click the project and choose `Properties`.
b. Under `Code Analysis`, uncheck the `Run on Build` and `Run on Live Analysis` boxes.

One final note: I have not yet tested using a .NET Standard library set up in this way inside a Xamarin project yet (this is the scenario that originally had me going down this road), but I will do so in the future and update
this answer at that time.

**UPDATE:** I have now used this technique in a released Xamarin app! The only weirdness is that you can't copy-paste .cshtml files to create a new one. It screws up both the original file and the copy and you have to go edit the project file to fix things. Instead, just manually add a new file as described above each time.

I hope this helps someone. And if anyone figures out what is going on with the weirdness in Solution Explorer, I would love to know!

Comment: Why do it this way, when there are so many more complicated ways? (kidding).   Incredible that this is so poorly documented elsewhere.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: This has definitely fallen into the "Am I taking crazy pills?" category for me. I just can't understand why it should be so hard to do what seems like such a natural application of Razor. Still hoping Microsoft supports this out of the box in some future update of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [RazorEngine](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/index.html)  library.

cshtml file intellisense is supported as per documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is "RazorLight" https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight
simple and straightforward

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to C#4 by adding the nuget packgage:

```
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

This will give you the `var` keyword.

Also, you can get intellisense for your template parameters doing the following

1. Create a new .cs file
2. Inside it, add a partial class with the same name as the one automaticaly generated by the .cshtml file. Something like that:

`public partial class htmlRazor : htmlRazorBase
{ public DateTime myDate}`

3. Add a constructor to this partial class that will take some input parameters:

`public htmlRazor(DateTime _mydate)
{myDate = _mydate}`

4. Add the following lines at the top of your .cshtml file:

`@using yourNameSpace
@*Make sure the parameter below have exactly the same name as the variable inside the partial class (public DateTime myDate). This line will be full of errors, but you can safely ignore them.*@
@{htmlRazor agrs = new htmlRazor(myDate);}`

You can now access your parameters inside the razor code by doing `agrs.myDate` for exemple.

As a last note, my razor project is actualy a class library (creates a .dll file). I reference this library from a second console application project.
I then create the html from the template like that:

`htmlRazor html = new htmlRazor(DateTime.Now);
string htmlTxt = html.GenerateString();`

Answer (score -1):

I usually use T4 Templates outside ASP.NET app: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb126445.aspx. There are several plugins for Visual Studio which enable code highlighting, for example http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html.

Of course, T4 is not equivalent to Razor and you should learn syntax in order to use it, but I think using Razor outside webapp is bad style...

Using T4 you can create from templates your own classes with custom strongly typed properties and constructors, and that's much more than Razor can.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I want to use Razor because I'd like to reuse/repurpose templates that were developed for a website. However, I will take a look at T4 as well.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.