# RazorViewEngine in console app cannot find View

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, .net-6.0, razor-class-library

I have the following

- dotnet core 6 console app
- dotnet core 6 Razor Class Libary (with .cshtml)

I'm doing a View Engine RenderAsync() that works just fine in web api.
When running in a console app cannot find the template, template is there in the dll.

[image]

*First question, what is the relative/absolute path to that cshtml?
I'm using: @"Templates/Pdf/LevelsEmail.cshtml"*

Console App startup

```
IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddScoped<ITemplateBuilder, TemplateBuilder>();
var listener = new DiagnosticListener("Microsoft.AspNetCore");
services.AddSingleton(listener);
services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticSource>(listener);
services.AddRazorPages();
// rest of deps
var scope = provider.CreateScope();
await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Runner>().ProcessAsync();
```

in RCL csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Trying to GetView or FindView

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            RequestServices = _serviceProvider
        };
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
```

Searching the ViewEngineResult

```
    var viewResult = _viewEngine.GetView(executingFilePath: viewPath, viewPath: viewPath, isMainPage);
    if (getViewResult.Success)
    {
        return getViewResult;
    }

    var findViewResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewPath, isMainPage);
    if (findViewResult.Success)
    {
        return findViewResult;
    }
```

Then rendering (this is just an example, problem is at fetching the View)

```
var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext, 
                        viewResult.View, 
                        viewDictionary,
                        new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, _tempDataProvider), 
                        outputWriter, 
                        new HtmlHelperOptions());
      await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
```

*Second question: is this possible to use RazorViewEngine in a console app (not a web app)?*

Comment: For your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080204/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-razor-in-a-console-application

Comment: @RahulSharma that's a hack but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Found one workaround, it is not the answer to the question, so I will keep it open, but it does the trick for me.

So:

Changed console app to web

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Program looks like:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);

builder.Services.AddModules(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

ITemplateService myBuilder = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ITemplateBuilder>();

MyModel email = new MyModel{ Data = InitData() };

string compiled = await myBuilder.RenderAsync(MyModel.Template, email, true);
```

Mandatory to have on services collection

```
.AddRazorPages();
```

rest of the dependencies required in console app DiagnosticListener and DiagnosticSource no longer needed to be explicit injected, web project takes care of that.

For me this is a good solution because this console apps runs in docker containers, I did not tested if this can run in a durable azure function or aws lambda function, I have a feeling is not, but it must to be tested.

Comment: Turning `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` is not working to me.
Every thing works fine when the razor library is used in web project but the same code fail to find the views when used on Console project.